# How do I fix missing module error module "./launchEditor" in react code?

Tags: reactjs

I tried to re install react package but still did not fix it

```
Error: Cannot find module './launchEditor'
```

Comment: jsx/js file name `launchEditor` or `LaunchEditor ` ?

Answer (score 0):

Doing a "fresh" install will work with Yarn or npm:

```
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json

npm install
```